# Generating Continuous signal till infinity

Tags: signals, vhdl, fpga

I am trying to make a AW generator using my FPGA. So I am writing data to FPGA DDR2 and from there using cascaded BRAM as fifo I want to produce the signals.

I want to read the same set of DATA (that i written on DDR2) again and again to generate my continuous waveform.

For some reason I can produce the signal but unfortunately i can no longer repeat it again and again.

I am using VHDL to design my system.

Please help me if any one has any idea how to do this. 
MAny thanks in advance to look into problem.

Regards

Comment: What is the exact problem you are running into? You can generate the read addresses for DDR2 in such a way that starts from 0 (assuming you wrote the data starting from 0) and go to N, where N is the last address at which you store data. Once N is reached, your next address should be 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

To read the same data repeatedly you need to creat a block RAM instead of FIFO. Major FPGA development tools (including Quartus and ISE) provide built-in functions for on-chip RAM and interface with off-chip RAM (which is your case). Your top-level design will be like this: in one process maintain a counter and let it count for ever within the range of the address of your RAM; in another process read from RAM at the address located by that counter.

Comment: Dear Daniel 
Many thanks for reply. I am using BRAM as fifo.
I am writing data (using raw ethernet).
to the DDR2. Afterward I have designed a cascaded FIFo using BRams(as cascaded to increase the depth).Power PC is handling this data transfer to my custom IP. Can you please explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: You system sounds complete. Could you please elaborate the complete data pipe? For example FPGA-> DDR2 -> PowerPC -> custemer IP? How does Ethernet help?

Comment: My system goes like this. Data Generated in Computer-->sent to FPGA port (Via Raw Ethernet)--> Power PC handle this communication and writes on the DDR2 -->Now power starts its state machine coded in User logic of Custom IP and fills the FIFO (made using BRAMS) and according to the instruction set via data sequence it generate pulse  at output ports.  Does it help you to understand the design. If not please let me know i will be glad to try to do it again. Thank you

Comment: Still not fully understand your system. If possible, you may summarize the problem in a doc and send to danshan@umich.edu. I'll try to help.